# How should I index my data in ElasticSearch to solve this situation?

Tags: indexing, full-text-search, elasticsearch, tire

I'm building a search engine for a game (path of exile). In this game, items have sockets.

- items can have from 0 to 6 sockets
- some sockets can be linked
- there are 3 types of sockets (Red, Green, Blue)
- when 3 sockets are linked (for instance), we consider that they're all linked to each other, not just to the closest one.

Example of an item with 5 linked sockets and 1 lonely sixth socket.

[image]

**My goal is to allow users to search for items with specific socket colors and links with ElasticSearch.**

A user would describe the socket combination like that:

"RRRBB" would be an item with 5 linked sockets, 3 red and 2 blue.
"GGG RB" would have 3 green socket linked and 1 red and 1 blue linked.

Still following?

When I index an item, I order the linked sockets alphabetically and by group size (group size might not be necessary): "RB GGB" would become "BGG RB".

And I would reorder the user input the same way before doing the search.

So, searching for an exact combination is super easy and fast(?). I wouldn't even need to analyze the data, would I?

But I would like these scenarios to work:

"ggg" would find "ggg rb" -> this is easy with just a whitespace analyzer?

But what I'm struggling with is:

"brr* r b" would match "bgrr r b" -> the way I'm doing things right now: as soon as a group has a *, I add * between every subgroup, so I would search for: *b*g* r b.
It works, but I think it's really inefficient, right? (even with small optimizations like remove the first and last * if the first and last letters are B or R).

Do you have an idea on how to index the data (analyzers, as a string or terms or...) to make this possible and fast?

The End.

Comment: wouldn't having a multivalued field, with terms being all combinations (1 - n) of subgroups get you a long way?